# Open a URL in Chrome (Kiosk Mode) and Reopen when it's Closed

Tags: c#, .net, process

I'm developing an ASP.Net MVC 5 app. 
The app supposed to be opened on a Kiosk machine. 
I've developed another startup exe file in C# WinForms to launch Chrome in Kiosk mode.
Now if a user closed Chrome by pressing `Alt + F4`, the app does not restart Chrome again.
How can I overcome this?

This is how I start Chrome in WinForm app.

```
 Process p = new Process();
 ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
 psi.FileName = "chrome.exe";
 psi.Arguments = "--kiosk --disable-pinch --overscroll-history-navigation=0 " + kiosklUrl;
 p.StartInfo = psi;
 p.Start();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check if the process has been exited.

```
 var isRunning = !process.HasExited;
```

or you can simply subscribe to an exited event.

```
 process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
 process.Exited += (sender, e) => {   };
```

Do not forget to turn on raising events.

Comment: I tried your codes. HasExited is getting `true` in 2 or 3 seconds after starting the process. In your second option, Continuously open the multiple tabs on chrome until I stop debugging. Could you please show me the way of using your code with my code?

Comment: oh, you right. Code that I placed yesterday won't work because it starts a new process like chain. I would search for something new

Comment: So the CodeProject article recommend you to disable buttons like alt+f4:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23955/Running-a-Web-Site-in-Kiosk-Mode-with-C

Comment: I've developed my launcher by following that CodeProject article. Here I need to restart the process if the current process went down in any matter, rather than pressing `alt+f4`